# Manual Reset Event Basic Question

Tags: c#

i am little confused about the manual reset event's wait one method , consider below scenarion

```
static  object objLock = new object();

    static int counter = 5;

    static ManualResetEvent mEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ///LeftShifting(10, 4);

       // RightShifting(3, 1);

       // Xoring(0001, 1001);

       // ExcahnageValuesWithXoring(10, 20);

       // ReverseBits(0);

        Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "Main Thread";

        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoSomeLongWork));
            t.Name = i.ToString();
            t.Start();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Current thread is " + Thread.CurrentThread.Name);

        mEvent.WaitOne();

        Console.WriteLine("Current thread is " + Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("Completed Long Running Process...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void DoSomeLongWork()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Starting Long Running Process...On " + Thread.CurrentThread.Name);

        Thread.Sleep(5000);

        Interlocked.Decrement(ref counter);

        Console.WriteLine("Ending Long Running Process...On " + Thread.CurrentThread.Name);

        if (counter == 0)
            mEvent.Set();

    }
```

my question is when i call mEvent.Waitone() is it going to block 'Main Thread' or the one of the executing child thread.

Comment: Be careful when checking counter == 0.  Another thread may have decremented the counter before the code reaches the if statement so that counter == 0 is never true for any thread.  You may want to use counter <= 0 instead.

Comment: that's not a problem since i am using Interlocked Class it will work like a lock with optimization as far as i know.

Comment: But the comparison is not within a lock so it is a problem.

Comment: No if you are only reading a state of a varaible in  threads and not modifying the state than it's not a problem and hopefully i am doing that :)

Comment: This is what could happen: Counter is 1.  Thread A decrements counter which is then 0.  Before Thread A reaches the if statement, Thread B decrements the counter which is now -1.  When Thread A reaches the if statement, the counter is -1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It blocks the main thread. That's the only one it *can* block. You can't force another thread to sleep. The main thread will wait for the other thread to "set" the event. This is very much like `Monitor.Wait`/`Pulse`.

Comment: Thanks a Zillion Mr Skeet for such a quick and straight forward answer. Some time when i read MSDN it says , Wait one blocks current thread executing so causes some confusion in my mind.

Comment: @Saurabh: I'm not sure why that causes confusion - the "current thread" is the one that's calling `Wait`. Anyway, glad the answer helped...

Answer (score 1):

`mEvent.WaitOne()` will block the main thread until one of the child threads calls `mEvent.Set()`.

Comment: Thanks a Zillion Mr Fredrik for such a quick and straight forward answer. Some time when i read MSDN it says , Wait one blocks current thread executing so causes some confusion in my mind.